# How to Refresh only components in certain 'box'

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Say I have a websites with 3 panel grid (just for example..) and I would like to have buttons inside each grid that only cause the contents of that grid to refresh so the rest of the page doesn't necessarily have to refresh.

How do I do that? 
I tried to have a form sorround that grid but it seems like the rest of the page still gets refreshed.

A Note - I'm trying to achieve something like what happens when you work with a picklist. when you move the objects between the lists there doesn't seem to be any page refresh...

Thanks!

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Which component library are you using?

Comment: JSF 1.2 with richfaces and myfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RichFaces, you should definitivly check the [Ajax chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#AjaxRequestOptimization) of the RichFaces manual. I think you will find everything you need to know there.

Here a small example for partial page rendering:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="update" reRender="infoBlock"/>

<h:panelGrid id="infoBlock">
  <!-- Some content-->
</h:panelGrid>
```